# animating SVG line transitions

Tags: animation, svg

Given two simple SVG icons, how would I animate the transition between them - ideally without complex JavaScript (e.g. GreenSock; toggling a class would be fine though):

```css
svg {
    width: 10em;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    stroke: currentColor;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: square;
    stroke-linejoin: bevel;
    fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6" />
    <line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <line x1="9" y1="6" x2="15" y2="12" />
    <line x1="9" y1="18" x2="15" y2="12" />
</svg>
```

(I assume both icons' `<line>`s would be merged into a single `<svg>` for animation purposes.)

Based on my own research, wading through a lot of seemingly conflicting documentation on the web, [CSS transformations](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/) are insufficient here (`translate` + `scale` + `rotate` results in a skewed image) and [SMIL](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) is no longer recommended (I also struggle to figure out how to make it work properly).

Comment: SMIL is fine and pretty simple for this

Comment: My understanding was that it's deprecated, but that, too, is based on somewhat conflicting information around the web. So would I insert four `<animate>` elements for each line (`attributeName="x1" from="3" to="9"` and so on)? Among other issues, when I did that, the `to` state didn't persist, i.e. was reset after `duration`.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your animation. Do you want to morph both ? Or maybe you can play with opacity or clip or idk but it really depend on what you expect. ANd for sure you can create a path morph with css Keyframes

Comment: I had imagined the first icon's upper line to be morphed into the second icon's descending line (same for the remaining two lines). However, I'm not too fussy about how exactly that happens; as long as the transition is pleasant to look at (the objective here is to provide/assist user feedback) and not hugely complex to implement/maintain, I'm happy to use whatever mechanism makes sense.

Comment: @anc it was briefly deprecated in Chrome but that deprecation was then rescinded following a protest. To persist SMIL use fill="freeze"

Comment: Thank you, @RobertLongson, that's both very helpful! I've also realized that I could use `<path>` instead of `<line>` here, which only requires a single `<animate>`  instead of four.

`freeze` also led me to https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/ which towards the end describes how to trigger animations via JavaScript, using `begin="indefinite"` and then invoking `.beginElement()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could probably use a little tweaking, but you *can* make CSS transitions work with the `transform` property. The key is the order in which translate, rotate and scale are applied.

```js
var toggle = true;

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('svg').classList[toggle ? 'add' : 'remove']('arrow');
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-linejoin: bevel;
  fill: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg line {
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.arrow .line-top {
  transform: translate(12px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
}

.arrow .line-bottom {
  transform: translate(-5px, 5.3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 1);
}
```

```html
click to toggle arrow class <br>
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <line class="line-top" x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6" />
    <line class="line-bottom" x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I had in mind, thank you! Your explanation regarding order also makes sense and probably explains why things appeared skewed in my own experiments. How did you arrive at those values though; trial and error or is there some math behind this? Also, do `px` values correspond to vector coordinates for SVGs; what happens if the image is scaled?

Comment: I just "eyeballed" it - I wouldn't call it trial and error simply because after rotating I could quickly tell what kind of offset would be needed to align the lines. The px values are in respect to the svg yes. If you scale the SVG itself - it will work the same way.

Comment: Thanks. While I ended up using SMIL for now (proved more straightforward to specify start and end coordinates; see response to @RobertLongson above), I will most likely come back to your CSS solution for future efforts.